# How to plot vertical lines in plotly offline?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

How would one plot a vertical line in plotly offline, using python? I want to add lines at x=20, x=40, and x=60, all in the same plot.

```
def graph_contracts(self):
    trace1 = go.Scatter(
        x=np.array(range(len(all_prices))),
        y=np.array(all_prices), mode='markers', marker=dict(size=10, color='rgba(152, 0, 0, .8)'))
    data = [trace1]
    layout = go.Layout(title='Market Contracts by Period',
                       xaxis=dict(title='Contract #',
                                  titlefont=dict(family='Courier New, monospace', size=18, color='#7f7f7f')),
                       yaxis=dict(title='Prices ($)',
                                  titlefont=dict(family='Courier New, monospace', size=18, color='#7f7f7f')))
    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    py.offline.plot(fig)
```

[image: Generated graph]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add `line`s via [`shape`](https://plot.ly/python/shapes/#lines-positioned-relative-to-the-plot--to-the-axes) in `layout`, e.g.

```
import plotly
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
import random

x=[i for i in range(100)]
trace = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=x,
                                  y=[random.random() for _ in x],
                                  mode='markers')
shapes = list()
for i in (20, 40, 60):
    shapes.append({'type': 'line',
                   'xref': 'x',
                   'yref': 'y',
                   'x0': i,
                   'y0': 0,
                   'x1': i,
                   'y1': 1})

layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(shapes=shapes)
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[trace],
                               layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

would give you

[image]

Comment: You could also use `yref: 'paper` which forces the coordinates to be relative to the grid and not relative your values.

Answer (score 6):

This is my example. The most important instruction is this.

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[12, 12], y=[-300,300], mode="lines", name="SIGNAL"))
```

The most important attribute is MODE='LINES'.

Actually this example is about a segment with x=12

EXAMPLE

```
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import plotly.tools as tls




    df1 = pd.read_csv('./jnjw_f8.csv')



    layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis = go.layout.XAxis(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = 1,
        dtick = 3
    ),
    yaxis = go.layout.YAxis(
        tickmode = 'linear',
        tick0 = -100,
        dtick = 3
    ))

    fig = go.Figure(layout = layout)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df1['x'], y = 
    df1['y1'],name='JNJW_sqrt'))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[12, 12], y=[-300,300], 
    mode="lines", name="SIGNAL"))


    fig.show()
```

*Look here too.*
[how to plot a vertical line with plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586773/how-to-plot-a-vertical-line-at-the-x-axis-range-median-position-using-plotly-in)

Answer (score 6):

A feature for vertical and horizontal lines is implemented with Plotly.py 4.12 (released 11/20). It works for plotly express and graph objects. See here: https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-12-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-and-rectangles/46783

Simple example:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks(indexed=True)
fig = px.line(df)
fig.add_vline(x='2018-09-24')
fig.show()
```

Comment: I noticed that if you try adding annotation_text to that add_vline there for a date axis, plotly will through an error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.date'

Answer (score 3):

```
fig.add_vline(x=2.5, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="green")
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: See here; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300846/10144278