# How to plot a vertical line at the x-axis range median position using plotly in Python API?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to plot a vertical line that's dynamically positioned so that when filtering happens, the line will move accordingly. For example, with the below code, I can plot a stationary vertical line at 25K which works with the full dataset as the median, but when the data is filtered to "Americas" only since the x-axis range is now 45K, the line is not at the median position anymore.

So how can I plot a vertical line that's positioned at the x-axis range's median position? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yankev/test/master/life-expectancy-per-GDP-2007.csv')

americas = df[(df.continent=='Americas')]
europe = df[(df.continent=='Europe')]

trace_comp0 = go.Scatter(
    x=americas.gdp_percap,
    y=americas.life_exp,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12,
                line=dict(width=1),
                color="navy"
               ),
    name='Americas',
    text=americas.country,
    )

trace_comp1 = go.Scatter(
    x=europe.gdp_percap,
    y=europe.life_exp,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12,
                line=dict(width=1),
                color="red"
               ),
    name='Europe',
    text=europe.country,
        )

data_comp = [trace_comp0, trace_comp1]
layout_comp = go.Layout(
    title='Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007',
    hovermode='closest',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='GDP per capita (2000 dollars)',
        ticklen=5,
        zeroline=False,
        gridwidth=2,
        range=[0, 50_000],
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Life Expectancy (years)',
        ticklen=5,
        gridwidth=2,
        range=[0, 90],
    ),
    shapes=[
        {
            'type': 'line',
            'x0': 25000,
            'y0': 0,
            'x1': 25000,
            'y1': 85,
            'line': {
                'color': 'black',
                'width': 1
            }
        }
    ]
)
fig_comp = go.Figure(data=data_comp, layout=layout_comp)
iplot(fig_comp)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really nice question. I added ranges to your `xaxis` and `yaxis`.

Comment: Then maybe you already heard about it but `plotly_express` could do magic. Apart for the median you can have the same plot with one line of code. After importing with `import plotly_express as px` you can run `px.scatter(df, x="gdp_percap", y="life_exp", color="continent",
           range_x=[0,50_000], range_y=[0,90], hover_name="country")`

Comment: Thank you @user32185 ! This is insightful, however, this still isn't giving what I need, which is really a dynamic vertical line at the median position of the xrange - so when the xrange changes as a result of filtering, the median would move as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the help of the @rpanai's answer and using plotly update buttons, the following solution is developed. Check this.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yankev/test/master/life-expectancy-per-GDP-2007.csv')

americas = df[(df.continent=='Americas')]
europe = df[(df.continent=='Europe')]
# med_eur = europe["gdp_percap"].median()
# med_ame = americas["gdp_percap"].median()
# med_total=pd.DataFrame(list(europe["gdp_percap"])+list(americas["gdp_percap"])).median()[0]
med_eur = europe["gdp_percap"].max()/2
med_ame = americas["gdp_percap"].max()/2
med_total=25000

trace_median0 =  go.Scatter(x=[med_total, med_total],
                            y=[0,85],
                            mode="lines",
                            legendgroup="a",
                            showlegend=False,
                            marker=dict(size=12,
                                       line=dict(width=0.8),
                                       color="green"
                                       ),
                            name="Median Total"
                            )

trace_comp1 = go.Scatter(
    x=americas.gdp_percap,
    y=americas.life_exp,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12,
                line=dict(width=1),
                color="navy"
               ),
    name='Americas',
    text=americas.country
    )

trace_median1 =  go.Scatter(x=[med_ame, med_ame],
                            y=[0,90],
                            mode="lines",
                            legendgroup="a",
                            showlegend=False,
                            marker=dict(size=12,
                                       line=dict(width=0.8),
                                       color="navy"
                                       ),
                            name="Median Americas",
                            visible=False
                            )
trace_comp2 = go.Scatter(
    x=europe.gdp_percap,
    y=europe.life_exp,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12,
                line=dict(width=1),
                color="red"
               ),
    name='Europe',
    text=europe.country,
        )

trace_median2 =  go.Scatter(x=[med_eur, med_eur],
                            y=[0,90],
                            mode="lines",
                            legendgroup="b",
                            showlegend=False,
                            marker=dict(size=12,
                                       line=dict(width=0.8),
                                       color="red"
                                       ),
                            name="Median Europe",
                            visible=False
                            )

data_comp = [trace_comp1,trace_median1]+[trace_comp2,trace_median2]+[trace_median0]
layout_comp = go.Layout(
    title='Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007',
    hovermode='closest',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='GDP per capita (2000 dollars)',
        ticklen=5,
        zeroline=False,
        gridwidth=2,
        range=[0, 50_000],
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Life Expectancy (years)',
        ticklen=5,
        gridwidth=2,
        range=[0, 90],
    ),
    showlegend=False
)
updatemenus = list([
    dict(type="buttons",
         active=-1,
         buttons=list([
            dict(label = 'Total Dataset ',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [True,False,True,False,True]},
                         {'title': 'Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007'}]),
            dict(label = 'Americas',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [True,True, False, False,False]},
                         {'title': 'Americas'}]),
            dict(label = 'Europe',
                 method = 'update',
                 args = [{'visible': [False, False,True,True,False]},
                         {'title': 'Europe'}])
        ]),
    )
])

annotations = list([
    dict(text='Trace type:', x=0, y=1.085, yref='paper', align='left', showarrow=False)
])
layout_comp['updatemenus'] = updatemenus
layout_comp['annotations'] = annotations
fig_comp = go.Figure(data=data_comp, layout=layout_comp)
iplot(fig_comp)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to add so called `callbacks` to your program, so that the whole figure is updated when the database changes. Then you include a `mean()` to the definition of your `x1` and `x0` shape definitions. However this requires you to use [dash](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the automatically set xrange, so that I can use it in the shape definition? (without using dash)

Comment: I guess that there is a way to plot this without dash. You can use a trace on the same legend subgroup and using legend false.

Comment: @user32185  Can you please post the code and I'll accept if it can create the dynamic vertical line at the median position as described above? Thanks

Comment: The easiest thing that come to my mind is two medians. On for each continent. They could be associated to one legend and disappear when the continent is selected out. As on this answer to have a 3 states median you should use dash.

Comment: I'm @user32185 I just changed my display name.

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite exactly what you asked. As I doubt you can achieve to show the median of visible traces only without `dash` as correctly pointed out by Mike_H. Anyway it could be useful if you want to use a `plotly` only solution. So if you are happy with this outputs
[image]

[image]

You can use the following code. Where the main differences is that we use traces for vertical lines instead of shapes and we play with `legendgroup` and `showlegend` parameters

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yankev/test/master/life-expectancy-per-GDP-2007.csv')

americas = df[(df.continent=='Americas')]
europe = df[(df.continent=='Europe')]
med_eur = europe["gdp_percap"].median()
med_ame = americas["gdp_percap"].median()

trace_comp0 = go.Scatter(
    x=americas.gdp_percap,
    y=americas.life_exp,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12,
                line=dict(width=1),
                color="navy"
               ),
    name='Americas',
    text=americas.country,
    legendgroup="a",
    )

trace_median0 =  go.Scatter(x=[med_ame, med_ame],
                            y=[0,90],
                            mode="lines",
                            legendgroup="a",
                            showlegend=False,
                            marker=dict(size=12,
                                       line=dict(width=0.8),
                                       color="navy"
                                       ),
                            name="Median Americas",
                            )


trace_comp1 = go.Scatter(
    x=europe.gdp_percap,
    y=europe.life_exp,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(size=12,
                line=dict(width=1),
                color="red"
               ),
    name='Europe',
    text=europe.country,
    legendgroup="b",
        )

trace_median1 =  go.Scatter(x=[med_eur, med_eur],
                            y=[0,90],
                            mode="lines",
                            legendgroup="b",
                            showlegend=False,
                            marker=dict(size=12,
                                       line=dict(width=0.8),
                                       color="red"
                                       ),
                            name="Median Europe",
                            )
data_comp = [trace_comp0, trace_median0,
             trace_comp1, trace_median1]

layout_comp = go.Layout(
    title='Life Expectancy v. Per Capita GDP, 2007',
    hovermode='closest',
    xaxis=dict(
        title='GDP per capita (2000 dollars)',
        ticklen=5,
        zeroline=False,
        gridwidth=2,
        range=[0, 50_000],
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='Life Expectancy (years)',
        ticklen=5,
        gridwidth=2,
        range=[0, 90],
    ),
)
fig_comp = go.Figure(data=data_comp, layout=layout_comp)
iplot(fig_comp)
```