# Is it possible to use plot.ly dash with JS directly, without python and without server?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Plot.ly Dash is a way to generate interactive widgets from declarative specification in python.

The final widget consist of two parts - UI front-end in React.JS and server in Python.

I wonder if it's possible to:

- Generate interactive widgets without python, with JS itself. Is there docs how to do it?
- Build self-contained frontend-only widgets (with all the data for widget already included in frontend) that doesn't require python backend.

Answer (score 1):

It's too long for  comment. I'm sure you already saw https://plot.ly/javascript/.

1. As long as you play with `buttons` you can have an interactive widget. See this recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55708317/4819376)
2. If you can work with `css` and `html` is not that hard create a frame for your multiple plots. It will act as a widget but it doesn't need a python backend to run. If you go for this route please remember to include `include_plotlyjs=False` to your `plotly.offline.plot` otherwise it's going to include a `js` in every single html and the widget is going to be very sluggish as every plot (html) is going to weight more than 3MB.